# Retrieving related model's data in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Here is the database tables in question:

```
Companies:
____________________
| id | name |
____________________

|   1| Unimex|
|   2| Solomex|

Users:
________________________
| id | name | company_id
_________________________
|   1| John | 1
|   2| Ricky| 2

Events:
_____________________________________
| id | user_id | details | date|
_____________________________________
|   1|        1| null    | 2014-04-01
|   2|        1| null    | 2014-04-15
|   3|        2| null    | 2013-04-01
```

What I would like to do is to retrieve events for a particular date based on company's id. What I have tried to do is the following:

```
$this->User->find('all', 
     array(
       'conditions' => array(
           'company_id' => CakeSession::read("Auth.User.company_id")
        ), 
       'contain' => array(
             'Event' => array(
                   'conditions' => array(
                         'Event.date' => date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow)
                    )
             )
        )
  ));
```

but this retrieves all of the events for the company, the date condition is not being applied.
In the best case I would like to retrieve only the events for one company for a particular date. Otherwise I would get by with returning a list of users related to one company and their events for that particular date.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Following are the relations between the tables:

```
Events:
    var $belongsTo = array(

        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ));
Users:
            var $belongsTo = array(
            'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
    );
```

Here is the query that I get:

SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`customer_id`, `Event`.`user_id`, `Event`.`project_id`, `Event`.`service_id`, `Event`.`date`, `Event`.`start_city`, `Event`.`material`, `Service`.`id`, `Service`.`company_id`, `Service`.`name`, `Service`.`service_nr`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`company_id`, `User`.`employee_nr`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`surname`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `Customer`.`id`, `Customer`.`company_id`, `Project`.`name`, `Project`.`description`, `Project`.`link_nr`, `Project`.`start_date`, `Project`.`finish_date`, `Project`.`project_nr` FROM `schedule`.`events` AS `Event` LEFT JOIN `schedule`.`services` AS `Service` ON (`Event`.`service_id` = `Service`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `schedule`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Event`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `schedule`.`customers` AS `Customer` ON (`Event`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `schedule`.`projects` AS `Project` ON (`Event`.`Project_id` = `Project`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1

The problem right now is that the company id is not taken into concideration, and all of the events are being returned no matter what date it is.

Comment: Why dont you make model of Events and make a relation with Users such that Events belongs to Users.

Comment: Events do belong to users, I will update the question with relations in a minute.

Comment: you containable is not working... As your comments on @Moyed Ansari 's answer , you should use `$actsAs` to bind `Containable behavior` not `$actAs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
$this->Event->find('all', 
     array(
       'conditions' => array(
           'User.company_id' => CakeSession::read("Auth.User.company_id"),
           'Event.date' => date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow)
        ), 
       'contain' => array('User')
  ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I’ve tried this solution and it works for me.

I made all tables with small letters according to cake conventions like companies, events and users.

This is **Event** Model

```
class Event extends AppModel {

    var $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

This is controller **Event** class

```
$tomorrow = '2013-04-01';

$this->Event->find('all', 
 array(
   'conditions' => array(
       'date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($tomorrow)),
    ), 
   'contain' => array(
         'User' => array(
               'conditions' => array(
                     'User.company_id' => CakeSession::read ('Auth.User.company_id')
                )
         )
    )
```

));

This will give you

```
 SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`user_id`, `Event`.`details`, `Event`.`date`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`company_id` 
    FROM `schedule`.`events` AS `Event` 
    LEFT JOIN `schedule`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Event`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` AND `User`.`company_id` = 2) 
WHERE `date` = '2013-04-01'
```

I hope this will work for you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There is some problem with the following double array after users and conditions: 'Users'=>'conditions'=>array('company_id'=>CakeSession::read  ('Auth.User.company_id')))

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have just tested it again and the problem is that all of the events are being returned. No matter what user or company they belong to.

Comment: I did, with no help. I have also included the query into the question edit. Would you please take a look at it?
The problem is that all of the events are being returned and not the ones that are related to a specific company.

Comment: debug this CakeSession::read  ('Auth.User.company_id')). seems like it is not getting value from session. you can try by hard code compnay_id for testing

Comment: it is getting the right company id. If you take a closer look into the query, there is no condition as where company_id is equal to something... Because Auth.User.company_id retrieves the right id.

Comment: See the updated answer I was repeating the associative array for each condition

Comment: Right now I get all of the events for the company, the date condition is not being applied.

Comment: what is the query now ?

Comment: it looks like containable is not working. please verify whether this behavior is attached to your model or not.

Comment: Containable behaviour is attached to every model class in the project.

Comment: are you sure about it ? it is giving you all related tables data

Comment: In every model I have the following: var $actAs = array('Containable');

So I assume it has to be working.

Comment: what is the version of cakephp you are using ?

Comment: Usually model names are singular. So It should be `'contain'=>array('User'=> ...)` and not `Users`. Unless you named your model `User` instead of `Users`

Comment: It should be as `var $actsAs = array('Containable');` not `$actAs`